# True or false: O(n^3 ) algorithm will run faster than a O(n^4 ) algorithm for sufficiently large n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am slightly confused as to how to come about this question.
My instinct is that the statement is true when graphing n^3 and n^4
However, when applying constants e.g. 100n^3, the statement is false.
How would I come about this question?

Comment: The key is `for sufficiently large n`. No matter where `c` there will always exist some large `n` where the statement is true

Comment: Refer back to the *formal definition* of Big-O. Only the limits as n -> infinity is relevant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The definition covers “for sufficiently large”. The Wikipedia image shows the point X0, which represents when C no longer matters.

Comment: Ah i understand

Comment: So.. true. Consider self-answering this question as an exercise, supporting the answer with relevant resources - including application of the formal definition.

Comment: So true as n -> to infinity n^3 will always run faster than n^4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they use the informal definition (which is really big-Theta), then the answer is obviously yes.

If they use the formal definition, then the answer is no.  And the reason is that saying an algorithm is `O(f(n))` means that you can produce an *upper* bound of the form `c f(n)` for all sufficiently large `n`.  So merge sort is a `O(n^4)` algorithm and bubble sort is `O(n^3)`.  (Not the best bound you can put, but both bounds are valid.) And yet for large `n`, merge sort runs faster.

Comment: Isn't the informal definition more like big-Theta?